# Negative filtering by filter_box or some other mechanism

Tags: apache-superset

Let's say I have a column named **Column1**. There are more than 10k different values for this column, but my goal is to display on a dashboard all data except few of them. Is it possible to achieve it in Superset? As far as I understand the only one option to filter dashboard is a filter_box, and I have to choose values explicitly in filterbox, so no way to use a negative filter. Is it true, or there is some hidden mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **limit selector** values option to provide the filter out values you dont need by specifying the column name and the list of values you would like to ignore using the appropriate condition like ***equals, not equals**, etc

[image: check here for the option in superset]

Comment: Thanks. But I have to hardcode the limit selector during the filter_box creation? It's not possible to control filtering values in the realtime, from the dashboard?